# How to force release UICollectionViewCell (or UITableViewCell) after deallocating the CollectionView (or TableView)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

In my app, I dequeue `UICollectionViewCell` cells using `[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:uid forIndexPath:indexPath]`

When my collectionView is deallocated, the cells get deallocated later when the autorelease pool is drained. Is there a way to force cells deallocation of a UICollectionView (or UITableView) when the latter is deallocated?